# How can I get clang++ installed by macports to use a non-system libc++

Tags: c++, clang, macports

clang++-mp-X.Y seems to trip up when told to use libc++

`clang++-mp-X.Y -std=c++0x -std=libc++ SOME_SOURCE_FILE`

Often generates errors which I do not see when using

`clang++- -std=c++0x -std=libc++ SOME_SOURCE_FILE`

I'm guessing that the system libc++ and system clang (XCode 4.2.1) are made for each other. How can I get macports's clang to use a version of libc++ that it will work with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/):

> To use your tip-of-trunk libc++ on Mac OS with clang you can:
>
> ```
> export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path-to-libcxx>/lib
> clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -nostdinc++ -I<path-to-libcxx>/include -L<path-to-libcxx>/lib test.cpp
> ```